# how to read tab info from microsoft teams sdk?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a hosted react app. This app URL was added to the content URL for a team's app tab. I want to read the context of the tab (basically I need email id of the logged user). I found documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context) for that. From documentation, I cloned **@microsoft/teams-js**. in my react app **componentDidMount()** method I am doing the following way

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.getContext = (context) => {
      console.log("microsoft teams context", context);
    }
}
```

But I am not able to see any logs after opening it from the team's tab. Can someone help me with how to read those details from this SDK?

Comment: Could you please try printing the context in an alert and see if you are getting the values from context? alert(JSON.stringify(context));

Comment: I already tried that but did not get any alert for that.

Comment: Could you please try to get the context inside the constructor after initializing the teams library? or Please some share some piece of code so we can help you.